# Creating a graph in Spark from a time series table

Tags: apache-spark, spark-graphx

Suppose I have a table with three columns; `user, time, place`. I want to create a graph of the `place` transitions for each user if the time between them is below a certain threshold; i.e., after grouping by user and ordering by time, create a directed graph of edges place_i to place_j from contiguous rows (i, j), incrementing the weight of the edge for each instance of (place_i, place_j). The source table's rows are in no particular order. Is this possible with the Python API? If not, how can I do it in Scala?

Sample table:

```
user,time,place
joe,1,A
jack,1,B
joe,2,B
jack,3,C
joe,4,D
jane,5,A
jane,1,B
```

If we ignore the time threshold constraint, the graph should have four vertices (A,B,C,D) and edges from {(A,B), (B,C), (B,D), (B,A)}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `groupBy` followed by `flatMapGroups`. Inside the map I instantiated the iterator into a list in order to sort it. Then I iterated over the list in pairs using `sliding` and created the edges.

```
ds.groupBy(_.user).flatMapGroups( (uid, iter) =>
 val result = ListBuffer[MySchema]()
 iter.toList.sortBy(_.time).sliding(2).foreach { case List(x,y =>
   result += MySchema(uid, x.place, if (y.time - x.time < Threshold) y.place else 0)
 }
 result.toList
}.as[AggSchema].groupBy($"src, $"dst).count.as[Schema]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a chapter in `Advanced Analytics with Spark` about working with geodata. It's chapter 8 I suppose. The author has a discussion about **Sessionization** in spark which relates to your question.

For you to have all the transitions of each specific user which are close to each other in time, *Sandy Ryza* calls this `SecondarySort` which is not completely implemented in spark core, but he provided some code to do that and you can find it [here](https://github.com/sryza/aas)

I believe if you read that chapter and follow the codes, you'll get what you'er looking for.